# Groovy rename a file

Tags: file, groovy, io, file-rename

I'm trying to rename files in a directory using Groovy but I can't seem to understand how it works.

Here is my script:

```
import groovy.io.FileType

def dir = new File("C:/Users/דודו/Downloads/Busta_Rhymes-Genesis-(Retail)-2001-HHI")

def replace = {
    if (it == '_') {
        ' '
    }
}

String empty = ""

dir.eachFile (FileType.FILES) { file ->
    String newName = file.name
    newName = newName.replaceAll(~/Busta_Rhymes/, "$empty")
    newName = newName.replaceAll(~/feat/, "ft")
    newName = newName.replaceAll(~/-HHI/, "$empty")
    newName = newName.replaceAll(~/--/, "-")

    newName = newName.collectReplacements(replace)

    file.renameTo newName

    println file.name
}
```

When I run this, the names of the files aren't changed as expected. I'm wondering how could I get this to work.

Comment: What's the issue?  How's it changing the name unexpectedly?  Can you add an example filename and the result (and the expected result) to the question?

Comment: The files' names aren't changed at all. I'm sorry if I was unclear

Answer (score 6):

There are a number of things wrong here:

1. Your `dir` variable is not the directory; it is the file inside the directory that you actually want to change. Change this line:

   ```
   dir.eachFile (FileType.FILES) { file ->
   ```

   to this:

   ```
   dir.parentFile.eachFile (FileType.FILES) { file ->
   ```
2. The `renameTo` method does not rename the local name (I know, *very* counterintuitive), it renames the path. So change the following:

   ```
       String newName = file.name
   ```

   to this:

   ```
       String newName = file.path
   ```
3. Now, for some reason beyond my comprehension, `println file.name` *still* prints out the old name. **However**, if you look at the actual directory afterwords, you will see that the file is correctly renamed in the directory.